# Augmenting red-black tree for minDiff

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree, red-black-tree

**So I have the following question:**

You have of set of numbers, S, that you are storing in a red-black tree. You are trying to add minDiff to the red-black tree which gives you the absolute difference between the two closest numbers in S. For example if S = {1, 18, 23, 62, 79, 100} minDiff would return 5 (|23 - 18|)

A) Show  how  to  augment  a  red-black  tree  to  support  this  operation  efficiently  while maintaining the O(lgn) running time for Insert, Search and Delete.

B) Show how to output the values of two numbers that created the MinDiff.  For the example above you would output 23 and 18.

**My confusion:**

I am stuck on the very beginning parts of the question, namely what to augment. I can think of simple and inefficient solutions such as having each node hold the absolute difference between itself and its parent. However, it seems like there should be some elegant solution that doesn't require you looking at every value of the tree to determine the solution.

I wish I could show more of my work, but I am completely stumped and don't know where to start!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information you add to the tree has to meet 2 requirements:

1. It has to let you calculate minDiff quickly; and
2. You have to be able to recalculate the parent information from the information in its two children.  This lets you quickly fix up the information in any nodes affected by inserts, deletes, and rebalancing operations.

The answer that immediately comes to mind is to augment each node in the tree with the minDiff among nodes in its subtree and the minimum and maximum values in its subtree.

```
node.minVal = node.left ? node.left.minVal : node.val
node.maxVal = node.right ? node.right.maxVal : node.val
node.minDiff = min(
    node.left.minDiff,
    node.right.minDiff,
    node.val - node.left.maxVal,
    node.right.minVal - node.Val
    )
```